# Packard Bell laptop outputs no image on the display when turned on

Tags: laptop, display

I have a Packard Bell laptop which outputs no image on the display when turned on.

If I attach an external display I get image on the external display. If I then press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the laptop display lights up and works. I can then unplug the external display until I shut down the laptop, whereupon I then have to go through the same process to get a picture back.

Starting the laptop with no external display and pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> has no effect.

This scenario is the same whether the laptop has an HDD and OS or is just booting to BIOS/Startup page. Is this some unusual BIOS setting or is something wrong with the graphics/MB?

Comment: We wouldn't know of any unusual BIOS setting without knowing the model information. Have you attempted to flash the BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

The first step I would recommend is going to your manufacturer's website and downloading an up to date video driver. You want to perform a clean install of this driver by uninstalling the existing one and then running the install for the driver you downloaded (This may require multiple reboots).

**Make sure you have downloaded the new display driver before uninstalling your current one**

The below instructions assume you have an Intel processor with integrated graphics and do not have a dedicated GPU.

Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Select Device Manager in the navigation pane

or

in the Start search bar, type "device manager" and click on the result in the list

Find the section labeled display adapters and expand it. Right-click on the Intel Display Driver and select uninstall(You may see multiple adapters here but without knowing your model it is hard to tell what hardware you're running). You will receive a dialog with a check-box asking if you want to remove the driver and driver package, select this check-box and hit OK.

You should be prompted to reboot, do so and when you get back to Windows navigate to the directory where you saved the new driver and run it. You may have to reboot one more time and then test out your display issues and let me know.

Comment: The laptop performs the same way even without an OS installed, so it is not a video driver issue,

Comment: @KelvinPatterson Have you performed a firmware update?

Comment: Not recently, the machine in question is a MS2285, and in correction to the original question, it is the F4 key, not the F5 (apologies, didn't have my glasses on)